# How do I center the title names of List of Figures and List of Tables?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I know for centring the Table of contents, the following code is used:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
```

But what do we use for the List of Figures and the List of Tables?

Comment: Change toc for lot, lof, respectively.

Comment: As noted by the previous commentator, page 7 of the documentation gives insight (http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf). Command: `\cftZtitlefont` Quote: I will use Z to stand for ‘toc’ or ‘lof’ or ‘lot’.

Answer (score 4):

`tocloft` provides commans to change the formatting for the main lists: the ToC (Table of Contents), the LoT (List of Tables), and the LoF (List of Figures). For example, `\cfttoctitlefont` allows changes to the font of the ToC; the corresponding command for the LoF is obtained replacing the infix `toc` with `lof` in the command name: `\cftloftitlefont`, and the corresponding command for the LoT is obtained replacing the `toc` with `lot`: `\cftlottitlefont`.

To avoid repeating three times almost the same command in the documentation of the package, the author of the package decided to use a placeholder "Z" representing either `toc`, `lof` or `lot`, so to refer to the three commands discussed above, the documentation uses `\cftZtitlefont`.

In your case, you need

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{showframe}& just for the example

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `showframe` package was used just to have a visual guide for the page layout.